# Atom Editor: How to require javascript libraries?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, atom-editor

I wanted to how I could require javascript libraries in coffeescript code?
This is with reference to the Github's atom editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/)
2. In your coffeescript: `require 'js-library'`